# ¿Cómo obtener las colecciones que estan dentro de documentos en firestore con python?

Tags: python, firebase

Verán tengo la siguiente base de datos en firestore, en donde las canciones son un documento de la colección BD_Canciones, y quiero acceder a todos los datos que hay en ella, las notas, los compases y las canciones que hay dentro de ellas, pero solo he logrado mostrar u obtener lo que contiene un documento.

[image: Mi base de datos]

Este es mi código:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials,firestore
from firebase_admin import storage, db

cred = credentials.Certificate('./clave.json')


try:
   firebase_admin.get_app()
except: 
    default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firebase_admin.firestore.client()
doc_ref = db.collection(u'BD_Canciones').document(u'cancion4')
try:
    doc = doc_ref.get()
    print(u'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict()))

except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    print(u'No such document!')
```

Y esto solo me muestra esta parte de mi base de datos:

[image: Lo que muestra de mi base de datos]

Answer (score 1):

Podes acceder a colecciones dentro de documentos, no podes acceder a colecciones dentro de colecciones, por ejemplo, para acceder a la coleccion `Compas14` dentro del documento `cancion4` tenes que modificar tu `doc_ref`

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'BD_Canciones').document(u'cancion4').collection('Compas14')
```

con .get() en ese doc_ref vas a acceder a todos los docuementos de esa coleccion, o podes acceder a uno en particular con

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'BD_Canciones').document(u'cancion4').collection('Compas14').document('nombre')
```

Si queres acceder a todas las canciones bajo `BD_Canciones`, solo hace un `.get()` de todos los documentos que hay dentro de canciones

```
doc_ref = db.collection(u'BD_Canciones')
```

Recorda que vas a tener que hacer algun ciclo de repetición , por ejemplo `for` para acceder a cada elemento y obtener sus datos

Comment: Gracias! Lo mencionado anteriormente si funciona, pero cuando intente agregar el ciclo for no me funcionó, ya sea que lo ponga con get o stream:
try:
    doc_ref=db.collection(u'BD_Canciones').stream()
     for doc in doc_ref:
         print (u'Document data: {}'.format(doc.to_dict()))
       
except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    print(u'No such document!')

Answer (score 1):

Con este código obtengo las colecciones que están dentro de un documento.

BD_Canciones es la colección principal.
coleccion_detalles son las colecciones que están dentro de un documento específico de la colección BD_Canciones
this.currentUserId es el id del documento por ejemplo: 'rOKEjpYiCreRV2vQsZTQ'

Espero sea lo que estás buscando:

```
db.collection('BD_Canciones').doc(this.currentUserId)
 .collection('coleccion_detalles').onSnapshot((snapshotChange) => {
     this.data = [];
         snapshotChange.forEach((doc) => {                     
             this.dataata.push({
                 key: doc.id,                         
                 name: doc.data().name,
                 type: doc.data().type,
                 compases: doc.data().amount,
                 ....
             })

         });
 })
```